# Adding hyperlink to call a video

Tags: beamer, video

How can I add a hyperlink in beamer so that while clicking on that hyperlink I can jump to a video or a program code in another pdf.

Comment: You could use hyperref with file target or just the `multimedia` package with the `externalviewer` option for its macros. For the other pdf you need a hypertarget within it.

Comment: should I include some package in the preamble

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For opening a video:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\href{run:/path/nameofvideo.mp4}{Click for video}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

to open a pdf on a specific page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\href[page=2]{file:test.pdf}{Click for pdf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(to be viewed with adobe reader )

Comment: It works with Evince PDF reader on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @omisson Good to hear!

Comment: This save me today. Thanks for the codes. Of course I used it for a picture instead of a Pdf. +

Comment: @Mikasa You're welcome!